# Issue to show a like counter in the front end in React JS (but it works in the API)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

first time I post here !

We're working on a group project and we have an issue in the incrementation of an item in our front-end. At the moment we can check in our console.log that the number is rising when click on the button.

Althought, we have to refresh the page to see the new "like".

So here's the code in our compenent.

```
import "./Post.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { addLike, createPost } from '../../lib/social-network-library-master';

function Post({post}) {


    const handleLikes = async () => {
        let result = await addLike(post._id)       
    };
    
    return (

        <div id="general-container">
            <h2>{post.title}</h2><br/>
            <p>{post.content}</p><br/>
            <p>Posté par {post.firstname} {post.lastname}</p><br/>
            <div className="boutton-like-container">
            <button className="boutton-like" onClick={() =>handleLikes()}> 
                like
            </button>
            <p>{post.likes.length} likes</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Post;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a state here to manage the likes.

Something like

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

const handleLikes = async () => {
  let result = await addLike(post._id);
  //setCounter(prev => prev + 1);
  // if the result is coming from api then instead just set the response that you get
  setCounter(result)
};
```

then in the UI you can render it like so

```
<p>{counter}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for answering so fast. 
That works, we tried that before. But we want it to apprear even after we refresh the page. 
The counter is present in the backend.

When we click on the like button it doesnt go up.
When we refresh our page, its there. 
We don't know how to make the new number appear whitout refreshing our page. 

Thanks for your help !